# Parcel without Node is possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

In my HTML, CSS, JS Project I want to bundle to make faster my website, minify and all the features that offer Parcel. How can I use Parcel with the CDN? or i can use that only with npm? I write this because i don't want to deploy an Express server with all that stuff. I thought to install npm, use the bundler and then delete node_modules, package.json etc.

Comment: Yes, a bundler is meant to be used once at build time, locally on your machine. The CDN only distributes the build artifacts.

Comment: so after i used parcel through npm and ecc. i can delete package.json and all that stuff??